# Android - SQLite insert byte[] fails due to NOT NULL constraint violation

Tags: android, sqlite, blob

I am trying to insert `byte[]` into `SQLite` database but I get `NOT NULL constraint failed` error. I checked the values before inserting and `byte[] toString() => [B@e9e5fac` and `byte[] length=> 32`, so it's not null for sure.

Here is my database table definition:

```
 public static final String TABLE_USER_BLOB_STORE = "user_blob_store";
    public static final String USER_BLOB_ID = "_id";
    public static final String USER_BLOB_USER_ID = "user_id";
    public static final String USER_BLOB = "user_blob";


    public static final String[] ALL_COLUMNS_USER_BLOB_STORE = {
            USER_BLOB_ID, USER_BLOB_USER_ID, BLOB_STORE};


    private static final String TABLE_CREATE_USER_BLOB_STORE =
            "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USER_BLOB_STORE + " (" +
                    USER_BLOB_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                    USER_BLOB_USER_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL," +
                    USER_BLOB + " BLOB NOT NULL" +
                    ")";
```

Here is insert method:

```
public void insertUserBlob(int userId, byte[] userBlob, Context context) {
    Log.d("userBlob","string value => " + userBlob.toString()); // [B@e9e5fac
    Log.d("userBlob","length => " + userBlob.length); // 32
    ContentValues setValues = new ContentValues();
    setValues.put(DBOpenHelper.USER_BLOB_USER_ID , userId);
    setValues.put(DBOpenHelper.USER_BLOB , userBlob);

    Uri setUri = context.getContentResolver().insert(MyProvider.CONTENT_URI_USER_BLOB, setValues);
}
```

Comment: insert it with this command `db.insert(tablename, null, setValues);`

Comment: @masoudvali do you mean that I should preform insert operation with raw query?

Comment: that's not a raw query. it's one of datbase helper methods

Comment: @masoudvali I tried it and Iget the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can insert with this method

```
public long createBLB(int userId, byte[] userBlob)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_DIALOGID, userId);
    values.put(USER_BLOB, userBlob);

    long transaction = db.insert(TABLE_BLBS, null, values);

    return transaction;
}
```

Just as an example:

```
    String string = "byte";
    byte[] result = new byte[100];
    System.arraycopy(string.getBytes(), 0, result, 100 - string.length(), string.length());

    DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
    long t = db.createBLB(1, result);
```